# Implementing Domain Event Handler pattern in C# with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I am trying to implement the Domain Event pattern in C# using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org).

I have simplified my code to be in one file that can be ran as a console app and have excluded the Simple Injector code to keep things clear for the purpose of this question.

The problem I am coming up against is that each event could have multiple event handlers and multiple events could be raised but I want to restrict my Dispatcher to only handle events that implement the `IEvent` interface so I put that restraint on my Dispatch method.

This caused problems as to how to get the instance from Simple Injector as each time the `Dispatch` method is called `TEvent` is of type `IEvent` (as I would expect) but I need to get the type of the event passed in so I can get the relevant handlers from Simple Injector.

Hopefully my code will explain this a little bit better:

```
interface IEvent 
{
}

interface IEventHandler<T> where T : IEvent
{
    void Handle(T @event);
}

class StandardEvent : IEvent
{
}

class AnotherEvent : IEvent
{
}

class StandardEventHandler : IEventHandler<StandardEvent>
{
    public void Handle(StandardEvent @event)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StandardEvent handled");
    }
}

class AnotherEventHandler : IEventHandler<AnotherEvent>
{
    public void Handle(AnotherEvent @event)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AnotherEvent handled");
    }
}
```

Here's my dispatcher:

```
static class Dispatcher
{
    // I need to get the type of @event here so I can get the registered instance from the
    // IoC container (SimpleInjector), however TEvent is of type IEvent (as expected). 
    // What I need to do here is Get the registered instance from Simple Injector for each
    // Event Type i.e. Container.GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<StandardEvent>>()
    // and Container.GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<AnotherEvent>>()
    public static void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent
    {
    }
}

class PlainOldObject
{
    public ICollection<IEvent> Events = new List<IEvent>
    {
        new StandardEvent(),
        new AnotherEvent()
    };
}

class StandAlone
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var poco = new PlainOldObject();
        foreach (var @event in poco.Events)
        {
            Dispatcher.Dispatch(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

I have commented in the Dispatch method what my issue is. Does anyone have any idea on how I should resolve this?

Regards,
Gary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution you need is a bit dependent on how the consumer of the `Dispatcher` calls events. If the consumer always knows the exact type of the event at compile time, you can use the generic `Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent)` method as you show above. In that case the `Dispatcher`'s implementation will be really straightforward.

If on the other hand, consumers might not always know the exact type, but simply work with the `IEvent` interface, the generic type argument in `Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent)` becomes useless, and you would be better off defining a `Dispatch(IEvent)` method. This makes the implementation a bit more sophisticated, because you will need to use reflection to solve this.

Also note that it would be good to introduce an `IEventDispatcher` abstraction. Don't call a static class from within your code. Even Udi Dahan (who initially [described such static class](https://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) a long time ago) now considers this an anti-pattern. Instead, inject an `IEventDispatcher` abstraction into classes that require event dispatching.

In case all consumers work with event types that are known at compile time, your implementation will look as follows:

```cs
public interface IEventDispatcher
{
    void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent;
}

private sealed class Dispatcher : IEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly Container container;
    public Dispatcher(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent {
        if (@event == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("event");
        
        var handlers = this.container.GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<TEvent>>();
        
        foreach (var handler in handlers) {
            handler.Handle(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

If on the other hand, event types are unknown, you can use the following code:

```cs
public interface IEventDispatcher
{
    void Dispatch(IEvent @event);
}

private sealed class Dispatcher : IEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly Container container;
    public Dispatcher(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Dispatch(IEvent @event) {
        if (@event == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("event");
        
        Type handlerType = typeof(IEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(@event.GetType());
        
        var handlers = this.container.GetAllInstances(handlerType);
        
        foreach (dynamic handler in handlers) {
            handler.Handle((dynamic)@event);
        }
    }
}
```

Do note that the use of the dynamic keyword has a few unobvious advantages over using the .NET reflection API. For instance, when calling the handler's `Handle` method using dynamic, any exception thrown from the handle will bubble up directly. When using `MethodInfo.Invoke` on the other hand, the exception will be wrapped in a new exception. This makes catching and debugging harder.

Your event handlers can be registered as follows:

```cs
container.Collection.Register(typeof(IEventHandler<>), listOfAssembliesToSearch);
```

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the response. The event types are unknown so the second option is what I need for my requirements. I am having problems getting the handlers though, the GetAllInstances doesn't return anything. I tried registering my events using the Register and RegisterManyForOpenGeneric methods but still can't get the handlers out of the container. I can debug the code and see that the container has the registration as I would expect. I think this is probably something I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: That's because you didn't register your handlers using `RegisterAll`. See [the documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#batch-registration). Basically, what you need to do is this: `container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventHandler<>), container.RegisterAll, [ your assemblies ]);`. Simple Injector differentiates between [registrations of collections and one-to-one mappings](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections).

Comment: Brilliant thanks Steven, I had forgotten about that. Thanks for your help, much appreciated you have resolved my issue.

Comment: The non-generic dispatch works. But the generic Dispatch<T>() doesnt work. When calling GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<T>>(), it does not return the handlers.

Comment: How is it possible that you can have a reference to container on a static method if container is an instance reference?

Comment: @CharlieOchoa that was an obvious typo. I fixed it just now.

Answer (score 1):

To use SimpleInjector and get the domain event injected dynamically you could do the following:

In the SI registrations

```
_container.Register(typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>), new[] { typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>).Assembly});
```

Then create a event

```
 public class PolicyAddressChangedEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        public Address NewAddress { get;  }
        public Address OriginalAddress { get;  }

        public PolicyAddressChangedEvent(Address oldBillingAddress, Address newbillingAddress)
        {
            OriginalAddress = oldBillingAddress;
            NewAddress = newbillingAddress;
        }
    }
```

Then create a handler for the event

```
public class PolicyAddressChangeHandler : IDomainEventHandler<PolicyAddressChangedEvent>
    {
        private readonly ILoggingService _loggingService;

        public PolicyAddressChangeHandler(ILoggingService loggingService)
        {
            _loggingService = loggingService;
        }

        public void Handle(PolicyAddressChangedEvent domainEvent)
        {
            _loggingService.Info("New policy address recorded", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "new address", domainEvent.NewAddress } }, "FrameworkSample");
            //this could be event hub, queues, or signalR messages, updating a data warehouse, sending emails, or even updating other domain contexts
        }
    }
```

Now to inject the correct one when you create your IDomainEventDistpatcher with simple injector you use a factory injector. This is the key to getting all the types and being able to look them up dynamically. By doing it like this we are injecting a Func into the DomainEventDispatcher.

```
 _container.RegisterSingleton<IDomainEventDispatcher>(() =>
                                                        {
                                                            return new DomainEventDispatcher(type => _container.GetInstance(type));
                                                        });
```

Now in the DomainEventDispatcher we have

```
public class DomainEventDispatcher : IDomainEventDispatcher
    {
        private readonly Func<Type, object> _handlerLookup;

        public DomainEventDispatcher(Func<Type, object> handlerLookup)
        {
            _handlerLookup = handlerLookup;
        }

        public void Dispatch(IDomainEvent domainEvent)
        {
            Type handlerType = typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(domainEvent.GetType());
            var handler = GetHandler(handlerType);
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Handle((dynamic)domainEvent);
            }
        }

        private dynamic GetHandler(Type filterType)
        {
            try
            {
                object handler = _handlerLookup.Invoke(filterType);
                return handler;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This now takes the IDomainEvent and creates the correct type and looks that up based on the Func provided.

This is better because now we dont force the dependency on the class to know about the DI implementation we are using. Very similar to Steven's anwser above (with some small tweeks), just thought would also provide a complete example too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a faster version using cached delegates. No dynamic and no reflection after the first call. Uses `IServiceProvider` from the default Microsoft DI but that can be easily changed. Expression trees can be used too, but they take more memory:

```
public class EventDispatcherService : IEventDispatcher
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Func<object, Task>>> HandlersCache
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Func<object, Task>>>();

    private static readonly Type HandlerType = typeof(IEventHandler<>);

    private static readonly MethodInfo MakeDelegateMethod = typeof(EventDispatcherService)
        .GetMethod(nameof(MakeDelegate), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static readonly Type OpenGenericFuncType = typeof(Func<,>);

    private static readonly Type TaskType = typeof(Task);

    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public EventDispatcherService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    public async Task Dispatch(IDomainEvent domainEvent)
    {
        var eventHandlers = HandlersCache.GetOrAdd(domainEvent.GetType(), eventType =>
        {
            var eventHandlerType = HandlerType.MakeGenericType(eventType);

            var makeDelegate = MakeDelegateMethod.MakeGenericMethod(eventType);

            var funcType = OpenGenericFuncType.MakeGenericType(eventType, TaskType);

            return this.serviceProvider
                .GetServices(eventHandlerType)
                .Select(handler => handler
                    .GetType()
                    .GetMethod("Handle")
                    .CreateDelegate(funcType, handler))
                .Select(handlerDelegateConcrete => (Func<object, Task>)makeDelegate
                    .Invoke(null, new object[] { handlerDelegateConcrete }))
                .ToList();
        });

        foreach (var eventHandler in eventHandlers)
        {
            await eventHandler(domainEvent);
        }
    }

    private static Func<object, Task> MakeDelegate<T>(Func<T, Task> action)
        => value => action((T)value);
}
```

And this is the event handler interface:

```
public interface IEventHandler<in TEvent>
    where TEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    Task Handle(TEvent domainEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bring this up again, but I found another elegant solution to this problem without use of a dynamic keyword and using minimum reflection.

To allow a generic handler of an unknown type, you need to create a non-generic handler interface and a handler base class with a "Handle" method:
BaseHandler : IEventHandler where TEvent : IEvent
which will have a non generic Handle method wich accepts IEvent
this base class will also inherit the IEventHandler but will not implement it, it will be virtual, so that concretehandlers can ovverride it.

Eventhandler interfaces:

```
public interface IDomainEventHandler<in TEvent> : IDomainEventHandler where TEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    Task Handle(TEvent @event);
}

public interface IDomainEventHandler
{
    Task Handle(IDomainEvent @event);
}


public abstract class DomainEventHandlerBase<TEvent> : IDomainEventHandler<TEvent> where TEvent : class, IDomainEvent
{
    public Task Handle(IDomainEvent @event)
    {
        return Handle(@event as TEvent);
    }

    public abstract Task Handle(TEvent @event);
}
```

In your dispatcher you can now call the non generic handler method "Handle" which will reridect a call to a more concrete method with a correct event type

```
public interface IEventDispatcher
{
    Task Dispatch(IDomainEvent @event);
}
public class DomainEventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DomainEventDispatcher(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public async Task Dispatch(IDomainEvent @event)
    {
        Type handlerType = typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(@event.GetType());
        IEnumerable<object> handlers = _serviceProvider.GetServices(handlerType);
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            IDomainEventHandler baseHandler = handler as IDomainEventHandler;
            if (baseHandler != null)
            {
                await baseHandler.Handle(@event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your concrete handlers will have to override the Handle method from the base class.

```
public class UserChangedHandler: DomainEventHandlerBase<UserChanged>, IDomainEventHandler<UserChanged>
{

    public UserChangedHandler (//inject dependencies here)

    public override Task Handle(UserChanged concreteEvent)
    {
       //handler code here...
    }
}
```

you register your eventhandlers as usual (this example uses microsoft DI)

```
services.AddScoped<IDomainEventHandler<UserChanged>, UserChangedHandler>
```

as you can see we do not use any dynamic keyword here and the reflection utilisation is at minimum.
Also this approach allows us to pass a generic list of events with a method

```
Dispatch(List<IDomainEvent> events)
```

Hope this helps.