# Entity Framework :Using Transaction Scope how to check whether DbContext has transaction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748872/how-to-check-whether-dbcontext-has-transaction)
using Entity Framework 6 if we begin a transaction using  `Database.BeginTransaction()` 
we can check whether a context has a transaction using this statement:

```
var transaction = db.Database.CurrentTransaction;
```

Unfortunately this way is not working if we used [TrasctionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) 
to begin transaction :

```
var transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
```

I'm just wondering if there is any way to check whether a context has a transaction when I'm using [TrasctionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Yes sure Transaction.Current.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Evk, Actually I've tried it and it worked properly,Thanks in a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using entity framework 6 you can use transactions in two ways:

- The first way, using `Database.BeginTransaction()` method:

  ```
     using (var context = new Context())
       {
           using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
           {
               try
               {
                   //Some EF Statments

                   Context.SaveChanges();
                   dbContextTransaction.Commit();

               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                   dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
               }
           }
  ```
- The second way, using [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) :

  ```
       using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
       {
           //Some EF Statments
           Context.SaveChanges();
           scope.Complete();
       }
  ```
- If you used first way you can get transaction instance using statement:

  ```
  `var transaction = context.Database.CurrentTransaction;`
  ```
- On the other hand if you begin transaction using TrasctionScope you have to use:

  `var transaction = System.Transactions.Transaction.Current;`
  to get transaction instance or check whether a context has a transaction or not