# C# : How to access variables from event handler with DI container like Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, events, dependency-injection, event-handling, simple-injector

I am working on a .NET core MVC web app.

I have a domain object method that perform some business logic and return a result object containing variables passed to view models. The result object has some variables that are from an event handler if a target event happened.

I am wondering how to access variables from the event handler with DI container like Simple Injector in sophisticated way.

This is a simplified version of snippet of what I am doing.

Class DomainA (has domain logic)

```
private DomainB _domainBObj;

/**************
* constructor
***************/
public DomainA(){
    _domainBObj = new DomainB();
}
/********************************
* called in Application Service
********************************/
public MyEventResult doSth(string arg){

    /************************************************************************
    * It did the job 
    * but I am thinking about if there is any approach 
    * that DomainA can get access to the event result if the event happened
    * without getting the event handler here using DI container in C#
    *************************************************************************/

    var eventHandler = DIContainer.INSTANCE.getInstance<MyEventHandler>(); 

    _domainBObj.doSth(arg);

    return doSthBasedOnEventResult(eventHandler.Result);
}

public MyEventResult doSthBasedOnEventResult(EventResult eventResult){
    var ret = new MyEventResult();
    // setting variables of MyEventResult
    return ret;
}
```

Class DomainB (Wrapper of 3rd party library object)

```
/**************
* constructor
***************/
public DomainB(){
     
     // configuration of the 3rd party library object
     some3rdPartyLibraryObj.OnSomeEvent(
           var event = new MyEvent(); // wrapper of some variables
           var eventBus = DIContainer.INSTANCE.getInstance<MyEventBus>();
           eventBus.Dispatch(event);
     )
}    

/***************************
* called in DomainA doSth() 
***************************/
public void doSth(string arg){
    some3rdPartyLibraryObj.doSth(arg);
}
```

Event Bus (Singleton scoped)

```
public interface IEventBus
{
    void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent;
}

public class MyEventBus : IEventBus
{
    public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IEvent {
        if (@event == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("event");
        var handlerType = typeof(IEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(@event.GetType());
        dynamic handlers = DIContainer.INSTANCE.GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<TEvent>>();

        foreach (var handler in handlers) {
            handler.Handle(@event);
        }
}
```

Ref: [Implementing Domain Event Handler pattern in C# with Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625363/implementing-domain-event-handler-pattern-in-c-sharp-with-simple-injector)

Event Handler (Request scoped)

```
public interface IEventHandler<TEvent>
{
    void Handle(TEvent @event);
}

public class MyEventHandler : IEventHandler<MyEvent>
{
    public EventResult Result { get; private set; }
    public void Handle(MyEvent @event) {
        var result = new EventResult();
        // setting variables of EventResult 
        Result = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question, because there are a lot parts of your chosen design that are unclear. There also seems some inconsistency in your examples. For instance, you show an implementation of a handler that is using a non-generic `IEventHandler`, but at the same time resolve a generic `IEventHandler<TEvent>` inside the `MyEventBus`.

The only thing I can do at this point is to provide some comments and suggestions. Here goes:

- Event handlers would typically be fire-and-forget operations. Letting event handlers return data can extremely complicate your application, especially because you can have zero to many handlers per event type, while they might wish to return different things. This causes a strong coupling between the consuming code (typically a [command handler](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/commands) or Domain Method). It, therefore, seems peculiar to me to have such handler return data. You might want to split this into an event handler that updates the system and a [query handler](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/queries) that allows you to retrieve that information. If possible, try to design the system such that to can retrieve that data later on (e.g. in a future (web) request).
- You seem to be applying the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). Because of its many downsides, you might want to reconsider this. For Domain Methods, [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/) is usually the most suitable way of getting dependencies into them. In your case, supplying the `IEventBus` to your Domain Methods seems reasonable, because you want to decouple down domain objects from the event handlers.
- If you're not already using them, you should favor using generic interfaces such as `IEventHandler<T>` over the a non-generic `IEventHandler` (with a generic `Handle<T>` method), because this simplifies registration and use of those handlers enormously, because you make maximal use of the .NET type system.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I look into it. The event bus and handler are actually library written by someone else. I just tried to recall what I saw. I am still new to C# and .NET. Any help with correct implementation of event bus and handler is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Anndexi, the answer you already [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30636387/2646970) does provide a good starting point. For simplicity, start with the dispatcher implementation with the generic `Dispatch<TEvent>` method; you can always change to a more dynamic approach and reflection later on if needed.

Comment: Since you are using a message-based design through event handlers, you might also be interested in command and query handlers. I've got a [reference architecture project on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices) that you might find interesting. It demonstrates these concepts using Simple Injector.